# Photo icons have generic picture only

Tags: windows-8.1, icons, photos

When going to a JPG photo folder OS C drive and opening it to view photos in an icon mode the icons only show a generic picture. If I click on the icon then the actual photo comes up. It seems like this problem just started happening. In the past I would open a folder and view icons and the photos were all there to view at once. I don't believe I made any intentinal changes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you show us examples?

Comment: In windows 8.1 I go to OS C drive, photo folder and click to open. Then there are view options. I click on icons any size. What used to happen is mt photos would show up in the icons. Now all I get is a generic landscape scene on all the icons that represent the photos in that folder. If I click on any icon then my photo comes up full screen.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Simple and easy. Go into your pictures folder. After that, press view on the upper left and go to options. From there go to view and the first check box "Always show icons, never thumbnails" I going to be checked. Unchecked it and bam

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my new installation of Windows 8.1.

After I had installed most of the regular Windows applications I was using in Windows 7, I started on a getting-acquainted tour of the new OS and its "ModernUI"apps.

The generic file type icons displayed in the Photos app really puzzled me, but a lot of Internet searching finally led to the solution: any installation of a recent version of the open source office suite "LibreOffice" changes the Windows registry of common graphics file types in an undesirable way, so that they are treated as a `document` rather than a `picture`.

There is a very long thread about the problems and solutions at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-pictures/windows-81-photos-app-does-not-show-any-photos/5b1740bc-d87d-4d07-afe5-c1a60cdecd55?page=6&msgId=9cdf0542-aab0-4a0b-85aa-e9f6d40b64fc

The simplest solution presented was a registry file which has to be reapplied every time LibreOffice is upgraded. The file must contain the following text and be named with a `.reg` suffix, then double click on it to load it into the registry. You may have to log out and back in, or even restart the computer--I can't remember which I did to get it to work.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap]
".wpg"="picture"
".dxf"="picture"
".emf"="picture"
".eps"="picture"
".met"="picture"
".pct"="picture"
".wmf"="picture"
".bmp"="picture"
".cdr"="picture"
".cmx"="picture"
".gif"="picture"
".jpg"="picture"
".jpeg"="picture"
".jpe"="picture"
".pbm"="picture"
".pcx"="picture"
".pgm"="picture"
".png"="picture"
".ppm"="picture"
".psd"="picture"
".ras"="picture"
".svg"="picture"
".tga"="picture"
".tif"="picture"
".tiff"="picture"
".xbm"="picture"
".xpm"="picture"
".pcd"="picture"
```

I hope this helps, but I am not (yet) sufficiently familiar with Windows internals to explain the problem and the solution presented here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a setting in Folder Options (called File Explorer Options in Windows10).

The solution is as follows:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Open Folder/File Explorer Options
3. In the small window that opens, there are three tabs: General, View and Search. Click the View tab.
4. You should now see Advanced Settings > Files  and Folders > Always shows Icons, never thumbnails (check box).
5. UNCHECK the check box and click Apply at the bottom of the window.

You should now see thumbnails of your photos. If not log out or reboot.

Hope this helps.